# Proving $f$ is onto and 1-1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Assume $\forall a\in A,\exists k\in N$ s.t. $k$ depended on $a$, for which $f^k(a)=a$

Where $f: A \rightarrow A$ and total.

Prove: $f$ is onto and 1-1.

I thought about proving it using the inverse ($f^{k-1}$ can be both left and right inverse) s.t. the function is 1-1 and onto.

Would it be enough? or is it an invalid proof?

Comment: The $k$ isn't necessarily the same for every $a$. For instance, you could have $f(1)=1, f(2)=3,f(3)=2$ which makes $k=1$ for $a=1$, but $k=2$ for $a=2$ or $a=3$. There is no reason to assume that there is a single $k$ that works for all $a$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

No, just give a direct proof: if $a \in A$ then let $k$ be given, and note that $f(f^{k-1}(a)) = a$, which shows that $f^{k-1}(a)$ is a pre-image for $a$, so $f$ is onto.

Suppose we have $a_1, a_2$ with $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ and this implies (by simple induction) that for all $k$, $f^k(a_1)=f^k(a_2)$ too.

Now we have a $k_1$ such that $f^{k_1}(a_1)=a_1$ and a $k_2$ such that $f^{k_2}(a_2)=a_2$. But then $f^{k_1k_2}(a_1)= a_1$ and $f^{k_1k_2}(a_2)=a_2$ too, so $a_1=a_2$.

Comment: Why is it possible to choose $f^{k_1 k_2}$? because at least one of the $k's$ is depended on its $a$?

Comment: @Combinatoric you can iterate as many times as you like. If you iterate $a_2$ a multiple of $k_2$ many times you have $a_2$ again. Likewise for multiples of $k_1$ and $a_1$. But the second paragraph tells us they will be the same for the same number of iterates.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Isn't it $k_1+k_2$?

Comment: @PeterMelech You need a common multiple. Try it out with rotations ..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Of course!!